# Instance creation in devstack icehouse

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-horizon, openstack-neutron

I want to create few instance having ubuntu installed on it using openstack.

I tried following steps

**Approach 1**

1. installed icehouse devstack

   ```
   git clone -b stable/icehouse https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
   cd devstack
   ./stack.sh
   ```
2. after successful installation i uploaded a ubuntu image

   ```
   glance image-create --name Ubuntu --disk-format  iso --container-format bare <~/sumit/images/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
   ```
3. login to dashboard and launch the instance (m1.small, RAM GB, total disk 20GB) using this image.
4. open the instance console from horizon dashboard and try to install ubuntu

Βut it shows required space(6.5GB) in not available.

Τhen I tried to install neutron and heat also

**Approach 2**

1. installed icehouse devstack

   ```
   git clone -b stable/icehouse https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
   cd devstack
   vi localrc
   ```

   my localrc looks like

   ```
   DEST=/opt/stack
   LOGFILE=$DEST/logs/stack.sh.log
   VERBOSE=True
   LOG_COLOR=False
   SCREEN_LOGDIR=$DEST/logs/screen

   ADMIN_PASSWORD=password 
   MYSQL_PASSWORD=openstack
   RABBIT_PASSWORD=openstack
   SERVICE_PASSWORD=openstack
   SERVICE_TOKEN=tokentoken

   GLANCE_BRANCH=stable/icehouse
   HORIZON_BRANCH=stable/icehouse
   KEYSTONE_BRANCH=stable/icehouse
   NOVA_BRANCH=stable/icehouse
   NEUTRON_BRANCH=stable/icehouse
   HEAT_BRANCH=stable/icehouse
   CEILOMETER_BRANCH=stable/icehouse

   DISABLED_SERVICES=n-net ENABLED_SERVICES+=,q-svc,q-agt,q-dhcp,q-l3,q-meta,q-metering,neutron

   ENABLED_SERVICES+=,q-lbaas
   ENABLED_SERVICES+=,heat,h-api,h-api-cfn,h-api-cw,h-eng
   HEAT_STANDALONE=True

   ENABLED_SERVICES+=,ceilometer-acompute,ceilometer-acentral,ceilometer-collector,ceilometer-api
   ENABLED_SERVICES+=,ceilometer-alarm-notify,ceilometer-alarm-eval
   ```

   After this

   ```
   ./stack.sh
   ```
2. after successful installation Ι uploaded a ubuntu image

   ```
   glance image-create --name Ubuntu --disk-format  iso --container-format bare <~/sumit/images/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
   ```
3. login to dashboard and launch the instance (m1.small, RAM GB, total disk 20GB) using this image.

   But now it displays

   ```
   Error: Unable to connect to Neutron
   ```

   Every time Ι list the instance it displays same error.

Can anyone help me out to overcome all these problems so that Ι can launch some instances and install ubuntu on that.

Comment: You will get only generic error messages from front end / command outputs. You need to check logs for detailed error messages and exceptions.

tail neutron log and nova compute log in two terminals. Then try to launch instance. You will get correct error message. Search with that error message might lead you to the solution.

Issue command neutron agent-list and make sure all components are alive.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to connect can be because neutron service is not running. Through Dashboard you cannot create instance without network. Use screen command in devstack to check if neutron is running properly.